What does "the position is also going against you" mean here?
I'm reading Hedge Fund Market Wizards, and there's one paragraph talks about shorting the housing market long before the crisis, and quote

They may not have a good business, but you know they are manipulating numbers. People love stable earnings. Isn’t that great? I hate stable earnings. It just tells me the company is not being truthful. And what I knew about the whole system in 2006 and 2007 was that the true facts were being obscured. The problem was most obvious in the credit markets. But you can’t be short because you lose carry [the interest rate payments on the credit instrument], and at the same time, the spreads get lower and lower. [A decline in the credit spread—that is, the difference between the credit instrument interest rate and the equivalent maturity T-note rate—implies an increase in the credit instrument price.] So you not only have to pay to hold the position, but the position is also going against you. Being short credit in 2006 and 2007 was exactly the same as being short Nasdaq in 1999. You just have to make money going the other way.

I looked into the background a little bit, I know the interest rate is going up since 2004, so does the adjustable rate mortgages.
What I don't understand is So you not only have to pay to hold the position, but the position is also going against you. The position goes against you? Does it mean it's too early to short the housing market in 2006?

@HartCO 1. don't answer in comments. 2. I'll give you a minute to write it as an answer as I was about to do exactly that when you commented.

Going against you means the price is moving in a way that doesn't favor your position. If you bet something will go up and it goes down, it's going against you and vice versa.
It's explained in the previous sentence:

[A decline in the credit spread—that is, the difference between the credit instrument interest rate and the equivalent maturity T-note rate—implies an increase in the credit instrument price.]

The sentence you ask about is a little awkward/redundant.
Yes, they're saying it was too early to short credit because the cost to carry the short was high and the credit instrument price was increasing (moving against you).

To further a good answer, The implication from the rest of the quote was that the short credit position was going against them because the banks and other agencies were not being truthful about the problems in the mortgages underlying the bonds they were betting against.

Thanks. It looks like when the mortgage rate goes up, so will the price to short it. Can you explain more on that?

The position going against him means that, for instance, if he is long the market is crashing and if he is short then the market is rising - but in that specific example he is referring to the options premiums he has to pay to hold the position - it's like if you go short on the S&P as a retail trader, you often have overnight fees and charges against your account. Same thing but at a much much bigger scale and all whilst the market was rising.
